# limit of accounts in cpi context

Tags: anchor, cpi, serum

we've been getting this error while trying to initialize a cpi context:
[image]

Does this have anything to do with the limit of the number of accounts in Anchor? Below is our code:

[image]

Below is the formatted code :

````
let request_queue_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let event_queue_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let bids_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let asks_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let coin_vault_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let pc_vault_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let vault_signer_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let open_orders_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let order_payer_token_account_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;//coin_wallet_a
let coin_wallet_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let pc_wallet_a = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let market_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let request_queue_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let event_queue_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let bids_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let asks_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let coin_vault_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let pc_vault_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let vault_signer_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let open_orders_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let pc_wallet_b = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let authority = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let dex_program = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let token_program = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let swap_program_id = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let rent = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;



   

let cpi_accounts = serum_swap::cpi::accounts::SwapTransitive {
    from: serum_swap::cpi::accounts::MarketAccounts {
        market:market_a.clone(),
        open_orders: open_orders_a.clone(),
        request_queue: request_queue_a.clone(),
        event_queue: event_queue_a.clone(),
        bids: bids_a.clone(),
        asks: asks_a.clone(),
        order_payer_token_account: coin_wallet_a.clone(),   
        coin_vault:coin_vault_a.clone(),
        pc_vault: pc_vault_a.clone(),
        vault_signer:vault_signer_a.clone(),
        coin_wallet: coin_wallet_a.clone(),
    },
    to: serum_swap::cpi::accounts::MarketAccounts {
        market: market_b.clone(),
        open_orders: open_orders_b.clone(),
        request_queue: request_queue_b.clone(),
        event_queue: event_queue_b.clone(),
        bids: bids_b.clone(),
        asks: asks_b.clone(),
        order_payer_token_account: pc_wallet_a.clone(),
        coin_vault:coin_vault_b.clone(),
        pc_vault:pc_vault_b.clone(),
        vault_signer: vault_signer_b.clone(),
        coin_wallet:pc_wallet_a.clone(),
    },
    authority: authority.clone(),
    pc_wallet: pc_wallet_a.clone(),
    dex_program: dex_program.clone(),
    token_program: token_program.clone(),
    rent: rent.clone(),
};

let strict: bool = false;
let min_exchange_rate = serum_swap::ExchangeRate {
    rate,
    from_decimals,
    quote_decimals,
    strict,
};

let cpi_ctx = serum_swap::anchor_lang::CpiContext::new(program_id_swap_info, cpi_accounts);

serum_swap::cpi::swap_transitive(cpi_ctx, amount, min_exchange_rate)?;```
````

Comment: Could you copy and paste the text instead of putting an image?

Comment: Further up in the logs, were there other warnings or errors during the build?

Comment: @JacobCreech , i updated the question above as you requested.

Comment: @sohrab, no errors on build and this is the full log : 
logs: [
    'Program F8awAgRRH8tqygALVvpaQmtC6tUFUCkgtbE8RhbaQXWu invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction:  Deposit Swap transitive',
    'Program F8awAgRRH8tqygALVvpaQmtC6tUFUCkgtbE8RhbaQXWu consumed 7729 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program failed to complete: Access violation in stack frame 3 at address 0x200003ff8 of size 8 by instruction #22299',
    'Program F8awAgRRH8tqygALVvpaQmtC6tUFUCkgtbE8RhbaQXWu failed: Program failed to complete'
  ]

Comment: Can you post the full logs instead of the pictures too?

Comment: There could be many reasons for an access violation. What happens if you create that massive struct into a `Box` and the function creating the `Box` is marked as `#[inline(never)]`?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, errors like this usually have to do with either

1. too many accounts being past in the context for the ix
2. your ix handler using up too much stack space i.e. too many local variables

possibly a combination of both. Potential fixes are boxing (`Box<...>`) `Account<...>`s in the context or splitting up the ix handler by making smaller helper functions that each do parts of the work.

If neither of those solutions work, or just for more info about the problem you could try doing a search for "Access violation in stack frame" in the [Anchor discord](https://discord.gg/vQaWpac33u). Lots of people have had similar issues with different solutions.

Comment: yes adding a box helped with the cpi context issue. However, we got this issue: "exceeded maximum number of instructions allowed (200000) at instruction #17266". 
Do you have any suggestions about how to fix this issue while keeping things atomic? You said that we can split up the ix handler by making smaller helper functions that each do parts of the work. Can we do that and still keep it in the same transaction?

Comment: Yes, even when you split the ix handler into smaller helper functions it will still remain a single instruction. However, the error that you mentioned has to do with the max number of compute units allowed per tx on Solana (200000 per instruction in a tx). Helper functions won't help with that. Look into the [`ComputeBudget`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/runtime#compute-budget) program for increasing the allowed compute limit. You can use [this](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/ComputeBudgetProgram.html#requestUnits) method in `@solana/web3.js`.